# Listening to Database Changes

Tags: mongodb, flutter

I'm working on a Flutter project, it is an e-commerce multi-vendor platform, there will be a **User Demo** and **Admin Demo**, I'm using **MongDB** for the backend. I forgot an important point, the user and admin can do changes on the database and this has to be reflected on the UI on both **Admin Demo** and **User Demo**. How can I listen to the database changes so I could retrieve that data again to be reflected on the UI since the I'm using **MongoDB Atlas**.

I've just completed a big part of the **User Demo**, where I retrieve the needed data from database once the user is signed in and any changes on data are reflected to database once the user is signed out only. for the UI updates I used Getx state management, but what if the data changes are made on the Admin Demo which is a single project, how can I listen to that?

the User Demo is an Android application

the Admin Demo is a Windows application